# Overhead of using PowerShell instead of C# for quering WMI from inside my app

Tags: c#, performance, powershell, wmi

I need to obtain some information about virtual systems on the hosts and also manage these virtual system. My application is currently doing it querying WMI, but I would like to turn to PowerShell scripts from now on. Personally I feel better using PowerShell for building WMI queries. I like its readablilty and the fact that the code is isolated into the script body. But I'm afraid that using it instead of directly querying WMI from my app will cause overhead.

From the point of performance is it worth it to struggle with writing WMI queries in C# if I feel more comfortable writing them in PowerShell script?

What are the other pros and cons in both approaches? Does PowerShell provide any optimization of querying WMI that quering directly from C# code doesn't?

Comment: How about you implement a couple sample queries in both languages, and actually *measure* if there's a (significant) difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there are no big overhead of using PowerShell for doing WMI queries. Both PowerShell and C# uses .NET so should be pretty similar regarding speed. On the same note, you won't get any special optimizations using PowerShell over C#.